# PythonCard - Can I launch a CustomDialog Stand Alone?

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, pythoncard, pycard

I have a CustomDialog I made to let the user configure settings.  Normally I want this to be launched from a menu item within the main application which works fine.

But during the install, I want to launch just the dialog to let the user configure the settings.  Is there a way I can have both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little supporting code you can -- see e.g. [wizard.py](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/PythonCard/wizard.py) which launches an almost-stand-alone custom dialog subclass "wizard".

Comment: I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\gpinero\Local Settings\Temp\wizard.py", line 1
4, in ?
    from PythonCardPrototype import model, res
ImportError: No module named PythonCardPrototype

Comment: So edit wizard.py to import those entries from the module you have them in, instead of from the module PythonCardPrototype that you don't have (or at least don't have accessible on your python path).